# How to get multiple inputs as integer in python for performing arithmetic operations

Tags: python

I am writing a program of calculator for adding, subtracting, multiply and dividing infinite number of values.

I have tried multiple ways like :

```
values = [int(values) for values in input("Enter values: ").split()]
```

But this return a list of values and we can perform direct addition of values of list using built-in function sum() but I think we can't perform direct subtraction, multiplication and divide on list.
So, for subtraction, multiplication and divide I create following function:

```
def multi(firstValue, *otherValues):
    result = firstValue

    for i in otherValues:
        result = result * i

    print(result)
```

In this function it takes two arguments `firstValue` as integer and `otherValue` as tuple.
When I give fixed arguments like:

```
multi(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

it gives correct answer but when I take inputs from user than I am not to able to give correct argument like I mention up:

```
values = [int(values) for values in input("Enter values: ").split()]
multi(values)
```

Please give me some solution or some suggestion for taking inputs in other way or changing the way of performing tasks in other way.

Comment: use `multi(*values)`

Comment: It give output like this : `Enter values: 1 1 1 1 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\5th sem\Python\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    multi(*values)
TypeError: multi() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
`

Comment: Then you've changed your definition of `multi`. The `multi` you show in your question *does* accept any number of positional arguments.

Comment: OK. This worked. But can you explain me that how it works.

Comment: Your function is written to take several parameters, so you need to unpack the `values` list.